# Issue when trying to set a variable with a getElementsByClassName on a HTML document

Tags: excel, vba, web-scraping

I am trying to scrape a webpage for a list of items. When I msgbox the  oHtml.body.innerHTML after the response text is set, I see all of the HTML, so that part is working. However, when actually querying the document to get the relevant elements I get an error.

I get the following error at the line beginning `Set dados ...`

> Run-time error '91';
>   Object variable or With block variable not set

Here is my code:

```
Private Sub Scrape_schedule()    
    Dim oHtml As HTMLDocument
    Dim oElement As Object

    Set oHtml = New HTMLDocument

    With CreateObject("MSXML2.XMLHTTP")
        .Open "GET", "https://example.com", False
        .Send
        oHtml.body.innerHTML = .responseText  
    End With

    MsgBox oHtml.body.innerHTML

    Set dados = oHtml.getElementsByClassName("resolutionWidget-state-list")(0).getElementsByTagName("li")
End Sub
```

Comment: Can you share the html or the url? Add your declaration in for dados as well.

Comment: If oHtml supports the querySelectorAll method I would go with that and a selector string.

Comment: Any update on this?

Answer (score 0):

There is no singular `.getElementsByTagName("li")`. The function `.getElementsByTagName` returns a collection just as `getElementsByClassName` does. You need to specify an index number or loop through the collection to collect them all.

```
Set dados = oHtml.getElementsByClassName("resolutionWidget-state-list")(0).getElementsByTagName("li")(0)
```

Comment: The OP is saying their line doesn't set. There is nothing wrong syntax wise with what they are doing